# How to call smooth-plotter from R

Tags: javascript, shiny, dygraphs

In the R version of dygraphs, is it possible yet to make Bezier-smoothed curves as with smooth-plotter?  It would be very wonderful to have that option, for someone like me who is .js-illiterate.

Comment: I might have a reason to work on this in near future.  Will let you know.